# PHP, error after function call

Tags: mysql, php

Today I moved my web on new web hosting and then

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /data/web/virtuals/41994/virtual/www/application/theme/admin-template/header.php on line 45
```

I dont know, what is bad on user::get('user_name')[0], I dont have any problems with this on old web hosting. I just wanna get first character of that ( if i used substr, I had no problem, but i got lot of, and i wanna know why :) )

PS: Similar problem with this:

```
$test = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('SELECT test FROM test'))['test'];
```

Comment: You probably have a different PHP version on your new server that doesn't support this yet

Comment: This syntax is supported by PHP 5.4 or newer.

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_query` in new applications. It's deprecated and will be removed from future versions of PHP. You're not doing any error checking here, either, which will eventually lead to problems.

Comment: Aside from the fact you most definitely shouldn't be using the mysql library!

Comment: What version of PHP are you using ?

Answer (score 5):

You are probably using php 5.3. This syntax is not allowed until 5.4+.

Use this instead:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('SELECT test FROM test'));
$test = $row['test'];
```

Ignoring the `mysql_query` hole... That's a separate issue.